# Moving documents to different categories

Tags: lotusscript

I'm trying to move documents from one category to another in LotusScript.

For example I have 2 persons and they have purchased something:

John:
    purchase1
    purchase2
Bob:
    purchase3
    purchase4

And I want to move all Bob's purchases to John's list using a agent.. I have no expierence with LotusScript what so ever and I don't want you to write the code for me. Can someone please tell me where could I find materials or guides how to solve this problem or atleast give me a direction where to look?

Comment: You only have to change the category field in the document of purchchase3 and purchase4 and refresh the view

Comment: Okay, I 've been stuck for few hours now and still have no results  but I got the idea how to solve it. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you add an image of the problem to your question?

Comment: @ThomasAdrian here's the link: http://imgur.com/B9fNMcm as an example i'd like to move the red squared items to the category above them. I hope you get the idea

Comment: Open the view in Domino Designer, check which field is set in first column,   If the field in the document is not editable you need to change it programmatically, you can create a simple agent without programming to change a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an Lotus Script Agent which processes the marked documents in view

```
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim collDoc As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim category As variant

    Set db = session.Currentdatabase
    'Get the selected documents
    Set collDoc = db.Unprocesseddocuments
    If(collDoc.Count > 0)Then
        Set doc = collDoc.Getfirstdocument()
        While Not doc Is Nothing
            'Get the current categories

            'Get the new categories

            'Set the new categories (+ use some of the old categories)

            'Save the changes

            Set doc = collDoc.Getnextdocument(doc)
        Wend
    End If
```

My sample code shows you how to get an handle to the marked documents. Inside the while loop you have to change the category field to move the documents to the new category.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I have no idea what so ever how to complete the code you wrote. I guess I'll need to find some kind of documentation and study the syntax until I'll understand everything.

Comment: http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/uafiles.nsf/docs/ls70/$file/lscript.pdf This is a language guide for lotusscript

Comment: You need to figure out the name of the field that you need to change. Thomas' comment above tells you how.  Let's assume that it is "Purchaser". In your loop, you want to have code that looks at the value Piurchaser(0), and if it equals "Bob" change it to "John".  That will require something like: If doc.Purchaser(0) = "Bob" then doc.ReplaceItemValue("Purchaser","John") end if.  Saving the change will require a call to doc.Save(true,false)

Comment: Also note: the sample code above assumes that your appliction contains only one kind of document. That may or may not be true. You may need to check the value of some other field, perhaps the field called "Form" in order to be sure that your code only acts on the documents you wnat to change.